# Retractable cable mechanism

Tags: mechanical-engineering, mechanisms

I am working (as a hobbyist) on a motion system where there be electrical cable (multi-core for signaling) going to the moving part. I have considered multiple solutions to connecting the cable to the stationary base (see below). One of the options is to have a retractable cable mechanism. I am aware of [mechanism that rolls the cable on a drum](https://go.travel/pub/media/catalog/product/cache/b5fe645b77afb63a8db566442e0f96d6/9/5/955_prod_a_col1_liquorice_black.jpg) that is placed in the middle of the cable. I think this option is not suitable for the solution as that will add weight to the middle and the cable will slack under the weight of the drum quite a lot, which contradicts the purpose of the retractable cable. So my question -- is there any well established mechanism for retractable cable that is fixed on one end (i.e. on stationary side)?

Requirements:

1. Mechanical (no electronics involved)
2. Automatic (no manual intervention needed under normal operations)
3. Compact (as much as it can be I guess)
4. Simplicity (simple mechanisms are less prone to failures I think)

Alternatives (that I am well aware of, thus not in scope for this question):

- Drag chain
- Coiled cable
- Sliding contacts

Comment: Check out the cable retractors used on vacuum cleaners etc

Comment: You will need a slip ring, if you want to only unwind in one direction from the hub.

Comment: @JonathanRSwift do you mean sliding contact in the ring shape? That might be one possibility, but I am concerned over the reliability. It is used for signaling (5v logic level), reliability in signal is everything here, which is why I am not really considering sliding contact here.

Comment: Hm, yes, the vacuum cleaner style would require a slip ring a.k.a. sliding contacts. Also from looking at it -- it is good for power transmission, but not so good for signaling as it generates a lot of noise.

Comment: I've used these for passing signals before without trouble https://www.ebay.co.uk/sch/i.html?_nkw=capsule+slip+ring

Comment: Modern steering wheels have slip rings in, too - sometimes just to pass button presses, but also angular position feedback etc

Comment: @JonathanRSwift hm. I think there are slightly different use cases for that. I.e. reading angular position of the steering wheel- you can miss 1-2 readings and that won’t hurt much (as long as next readings succeed). But in case when there is a single signal that must not be missed - the risk is quite high I think. Also seeing those prices are hurting me :D

Comment: Without knowing more about your application, I can't help any further then - Surely there is a way to make your signal processing somewhat error tolerant? With enough space, you could simply have a long length of static cable, and allow it to twist as the coil is wound in? Why do the prices hurt? £5 for a slip ring, including delivery, seems quite reasonable!